# AKMicrophone causes SIGABRT error - A bug?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I found a post that has the same error in the same situation here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/audiokit/SmyuzPJQ6wU

Same as this poster - I'm using the source. However, at the end of the post the user does not say what he did to fix the issue.

I'm currently using an unaltered "ExtendingAudioKitUsingSource" example as I need to add some functionality to audiokit. (unaltered outside of using my provisioning profile and adding "let m = AKMicrophone()" in ViewController.swift.

I receive these errors:

```
 2018-08-31 15:16:50.684 ExtendingAudioKit[6800:8850964] 15:16:50.683 
 ERROR:    [0x39058000] AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:452: 
 ___ZN13AVAudioIOUnit9EnableBusEm_block_invoke: error -10849

 2018-08-31 15:16:50.688 ExtendingAudioKit[6800:8850964] *** 
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -10849'
```

which traces back to line 46 in AKMicrophone.swift to init(): AudioKit.engine.connect(AudioKit.engine.inputNode, to: self.avAudioNode, format: nil)

I've had no issues using AKMicrphone() outside of this project.

Comment: Update: I managed to fix this problem - although I'm not sure why this worked. Just shots in the dark.

I started the project over from scratch and received a ton of Umbrella Header errors stating that my header files were not included. I tracked down each .hpp and .h file with the error and changed it's access type from "public" to "project" - which got rid of the error.

Following that, I received errors for "#include AKDSPBase.hpp" file not found. Changing it to "#include <AudioKit/AKDSPBase.hpp> fixed it (no idea why)

Added "let mic = AKMicrophone()" to the new project. No error.

Comment: Update2: the error is back. I used baby steps here. 1) Added "let mic = AKMicrophone(). App runs. No errors. 2) Added a AKBooster. App runs. No Errors. 3) Added override func viewDidAppear(...other stuff) + AudioKit.output = booster; AudioKit.start(). Received SIGABRT in AKMicrophone.
4) control-z back to original unmodified. Works. No errors. 5) Added let mic = AKMicrophone(). Application terminates with SIGABRT.

This makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Update3: started the ExtendingAudioKitFromSource project over yet again from a fresh copy. Fixed the warnings for umbrella headers and AKDSPBase.hpp, added "let mic = AKMicrophone()" to viewDidLoad() inside ViewController.swift. Received the error again.

Comment: The umbrella header stuff is all a red herring, no reason the microphone should be related to DSPBase.  Can you share a project?

Comment: FYI, looks like Stephane addressed the public header issues in the latest develop branch of AudioKit.

Comment: I managed to get a new project working using the source and the AKMicrophone issue did not occur. However, here is the project if you want to see if there is an issue with it: https://expirebox.com/download/46ce3af490453f610dff80bee3778fc1.html
I worked directly with the unzipped source example to ensure I wasn't touching anything except what is already there and to eliminate dependency issues. Note: this is using the source from Github, not your main site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed an AKMicrophone bug in AudioKit v4.5.1 that may have fixed this for you.  If not, I'll withdraw this answer, but please check it out and let me know.